# Conjunction vs Disjunction precedence in prolog

Tags: prolog

From what i know, conjunction has greater precedence than disjunction.

We have the following knowledge base:

```
a(1).
a(2,3).
a(3,2).
a(4,5,3).
b.
b(1,2).
b(3).
c.
```

Our goal is:

```
?- a(X,Y);b(Z),c,fail,d.
```

So here's the problem:
My teacher says that the goal gets broken into 4 subgoals, connected by conjunction:

```
(a(X,Y);b(Z)),
c,
fail,
d.
```

and that i shouldn't get no results when executing this query.
But conjunction has greater precedence, right?
Isn't the goal supposed to be broken into two subgoals(not four), connected by disjunction:

```
a(X,Y);
b(Z),c,fail,d.
```

So now I'm wondering who's right and who's wrong.
Can somebody explain?

**I'm actually getting results when i execute the query.

Comment: The documentation clearly states that `,` had higher precedence than `;`. Your interpretation is correct, and your test confirms it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation!

Comment: @lurker I'm new to prolog, and I find this phenomenon, too. But where can I find the offical doc of prolog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is primarily a misunderstanding that's due to the overloaded use of the word "precedence".

Prolog operators are defined by the extensible predicate `op(+Precedence, +Type, :Name)` where `Precedence` is an integer between 0 and 1200, `Type` specifies associativity, and `Name` gives the actual operator.

This table shows some predefined operators:

```
1100    xfy ;, |
1000    xfy ,
```

For historical reasons, a **smaller** integer value of `Precedence` means that an operator binds **tighter** (i.e., that it has **higher** precedence).

So the precedence of the disjunction operator is **lower** than the one of the conjunction operator, because its value of `Precedence` is higher.